# Ursprung von Baulöwe

Tags: etymology, idiom

Weiß jemand, woher der Begriff

> Baulöwe,

laut Duden ein

> "Bauunternehmer oder Bauherr, der [mit zweifelhaften Methoden] durch Errichten, Verkaufen o. Ä. vieler Bauten großen Profit zu machen versucht"

kommt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn man ["Woher kommt das schwarze Schaf?: Was hinter unseren Wörtern steckt"](http://books.google.de/books?id=A_uvgCF8sWYC&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=baul%C3%B6we%20salonl%C3%B6we#v=onepage&q=baul%C3%B6we%20salonl%C3%B6we&f=false) von *Wolfgang Seidel* Glauben schenken mag, so ist `Baulöwe` (irgendwann) als Analogon zu `Salonlöwe` entstanden, was wiederum eine Übernahme vom englischen `social lion` sein soll, welches auf das Bild des Löwen als König der Tiere verweist. Zumindest im Englischen ist der Löwe in dieser Bedeutung offenbar präsent, man vergleiche ["to lionize"](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=lionize&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) = umschwärmen, vergöttern.

Für den Salonlöwen erscheint mir das glaubhaft; was die Übertragung vom Salon ins Baugewerbe angeht, kommt mir das noch etwas spekulativ vor. Ich habe bislang aber nichts weiter dazu gefunden.

Answer (score 5):

> Der Löwe

ist ein Tier, welches (klassischerweise) in freier Wildbahn lebt, also in einer Welt ohne Regeln von Menschenhand. Er nimmt sich einfach, was er *braucht* - und  das ist nicht gerade wenig.

Man stelle sich einen Löwen vor, der vor der Jagd den Gesetzgeber befragt, und sich überdies Gedanken darüber macht, ob denn die Antilope (nach deren Verzehr) dann noch für ihre Jungen sorgen könnte. Oder ob er die Überbleibsel vielleicht noch wegräumen sollte.